# is Polymorphism also applies in Abstract Classes?

Tags: java, oop

A common argument is that Polymorphism only applies to interfaces and not abstract classes.

Is the relationship of as Abstract parent class to a concrete class that extends it considered a polymorphism?

```
List list = new Arraylist()// Polymorphism as List is an interface
AbstractClass parent = new Child(); // Is this also considered polymorphic?
```

Comment: Before stating that an argument is "common" you should at least validate it is considered "common" by anyone else but you.

Comment: Can you show me any example of where this is argued?  I have never heard this before and I couldn't find it with google.

Answer (score 3):

> Common argument is Polymorphism only applies to Code to interface and Not abstract classes.

That "argument" is factually incorrect.

Polymorphism *works* just fine in Java whether you are using interfaces, abstract classes or non-abstract classes.  (There are questions about which is best for long term maintainability, but that is a different topic.)

---

I'd be curious where you found that "argument".  Can you provide a URL?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  That is polymorphic.......