# Is it a good/common practice to use abstract classes in polymorphism in Java?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, abstract-class

In all examples I have seen that interfaces are used to achieve  polymorphism. Now we have the following code with abstract class

```
AbstractClass parent = new Child();
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937840/is-polymorphism-also-applies-in-abstract-classes) the man stated that

> A common argument is that Polymorphism only applies to interfaces and
>   not abstract classes.

I think he meant they are usually interfaces that are used in polymorphism in Java. As I see many people found his question silly and wanted URL. This [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/interfaces-vs-abstract-classes.html) what I found. So my question is it a good/common practice to use abstract classes in polymorphism (as in my example - because polymorphism is very wide definition) in Java?

Comment: The provided link is wrong. It's easily arguable you *should* use interfaces for *most* polymorphism, but obviously there are cases where common base classes, abstract or not, are the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is good practice to use the most general parent that meets the contract; if the interface defines all of the function signatures you need then use them rather than abstract classes implementing that interface. The article [Design Principles from Design Patterns](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html) by Bill Venners in discussion with Erich Gamma goes into detail.

Comment: Just to add to this, as an example, you could use (java.util) ``AbstractList list = new ArrayList()``.  However, using the ``List`` interface would be better, because you can change the implementation to ``LinkedList`` or ``CopyOnWriteArrayList`` easily without affecting other code.  ``LinkedList`` and ``CopyOnWriteArrayList`` are not subclasses of ``AbstractList``.  By using an abstract class when an interface is available you complicate future refactors.

Comment: @blalasaadri Thank you for your time. Can you explain "In Java when you add a new method to an interface, you break all your clients"?. I can't get the point. We have two classes a client and a server. The server implements interface. Why will we break all clients if they work according to the previous interface?

Comment: @brettw Thank you for your time. Can you answer the same question?

Comment: This is probably referring to the fact that when you change an interface all implementing classes must then also be changed to fit the new interface. If you have a client and a server that both use the same interface (well, classes that implement the interface) you'll have to modify both. If however you change the implementation but it still fits the interface it can still be used as before.

Answer (score 1):

One of their best uses is where you have a common behaviour between "childs".

Your interface

```
interface Drawable{
    void paint();
}
```

An abstract class with common code

```
abstract class AbstractRectangularObject implements Drawable{

    public void paint(){
         paintVertices();
         //your code to fill body
    }

    //Abstract method that all subclases needs to implement
    protected abstract void paintVertices();

}
```

Your real subclasses

```
class Rectangle extends AbstractRectangularObject {
     protected void paintVertices(){
         //code to pain vertices
     }
}
```

-

```
class RoundRectangle extends AbstractRectangularObject {
     protected void paintVertices(){
         //code to pain vertices
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You have common functinality and properties to share between child classes and at the same time the class itself is too abstract to have instance, it will be good practice to use abstract class. If no I will prefer to use interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes.  It is always good practice to use the least specific type necessary.  This applies in to concrete super classes, too, not just abstract classes and interfaces.

```
public class MyClass{} // not an interface and not abstract
public class SubClass extends MyClass{}

public class OtherClass{
    public MyClass getMyClass(){
         return new SubClass();
    }
]
```

In practice, it depends on the situation.  If everything is contained within the scope of say one method, it really doesn't matter.

```
public void doStuff(){ // void method, so never going return any details
   AbstractFoo foo1= new ConcreteFoo();
   // no better than
   ConcreteFoo foo2 = new ConcreteFoo();
   // because nothing external to this method will ever know 
}
```

However, the reason behind having developers *always* use the least specific implementation (or interface) is to just make it a habit.

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on your context.

Example:

```
 // Abstract class template
abstract class AbstractFirst {
  public void doSomething(){
    this.doOne();
    this.doSecond();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Test");
  }
   public abstract void doOne();
   public abstract void doSecond();
}

// Concrete implementation
class ConcreteFirst extends AbstractFirst {
   public void doOne(){System.out.print("One"); }       // must be implemented
   public void doSecond(){System.out.print("Second"); } // must be implemented

   public static void main(String[] args){
       ConcreteFirst cf = new ConcreteFirst();
       c.doSomething();
   }
}
```

This prints

```
OneSecond 
Test
```

to console. This is not possible with Interfaces. This pattern is called "Template method pattern" and is one of the GoF Patterns

Comment: I think the question was referring to declaring an object as an instance of an abstract class, i.e. `AbstractFirst af = new ConcreteFirst();` not whether interfaces should be used instead of abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your question there's not such opinion that say it's a bad practice to use polimorphism, it's a good practice to use it where it applies, but it depends on usecases where you define the requirements for the classes to be pure virtual aka interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

As to my experience, abstract class always contains partial implementation of some interface. This is the case for EJBs, for example. Its a better design to keep API and its implementation separate, even partial. So Id recommend make an interface and an abstract class. But for references use interface rather then abstract class.